What are these hinges called?
We have some closet doors that are six-panel doors installed directly onto the drywall without frames. They use a special kind of L-shaped hinges installed on the two corners of the door shown below. They are bent and I need replacement, but I don't know what they are called and where to find replacement.
Does anyone know what they are called? And where might I find a replacement?


examine the hinge assembly carefully... there may be a part number printed on it

custom made by the OEM

You may want to look for beefier hinges than these, too. These look like the doors may be too heavy for the hinge design. (Or some toddler thought the doors made a good swing once...)

What you have are pivot hinges. they are usually used for cabinet doors, but can be on other devices as well.
A google search  of "pivot hinge" will bring up many retailers. I often find "special" parts for cabinets, doors or furniture at Rockler.com

Lot at other woodworking supply jous s, since they all need to supply a variety of parts for different project designs. (My local Rockler closed. I was too busy to hit the inventory clearance sale, alas.)
